# Would like a more effective way to do a mutiple query using SQL in ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

So I have two queries made against the same table. The query works but my results come back a bit slow. I'm also using two different variables (Shipment_D2 and Count_D2)
Is there a better way to combine multiple queries while using different variables instead of opening a new connection every time I make a query?

```
 <% 
Set rscount11 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT Count FROM DivisionNew WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) AND
JMSDay = '" & smDateArray (Weekday(date)) &"' AND Section = 'D2' order by JMS_UpdateDateTime desc" 
rscount11.Open sql, db

Count_D2 = rscount11 ("Count")

%>


 <% 
Set rscount12 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT Shipment FROM DivisionNew WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) AND
 JMSDay = '" & smDateArray (Weekday(date)) &"' AND Section = 'D2' order by JMS_UpdateDateTime desc" 
rscount12.Open sql, db

Shipment_D2 = rscount12 ("Shipment")

 %>
```

Comment: I take it `count` is a field, and not an **aggregation**?  Also, have you considered whether the performance is slow in the DB? and `indexes` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not include both columns in the SELECT query?

```
 <% 
Set rscount11 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT Count, Shipment FROM DivisionNew WHERE JMS_UpdateDateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) AND
JMSDay = '" & smDateArray (Weekday(date)) &"' AND Section = 'D2' order by JMS_UpdateDateTime desc" 
rscount11.Open sql, db

Count_D2 = rscount11 ("Count")
Shipment_D2 = rscount11 ("Shipment")

%>
```

Comment: Ahhh, I overlooked that.  I made the change. Works great! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't ever use `select *` if all you need is a count. You are transfering all the records from the DB into memory which is horribly inefficient. Let the Database do the work for you.

Your first query can be rewritten as follows, where the DB does the work and you only retrieve a sinlge value into memory rather than a pottentially huge dataset. Use the same apporach for your second query.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM DivisionNew WHERE ...
```

Comment: Still figuring out if there is a way to combine queries.

Comment: @Jimmy I must be missign something, but what is the difference between your 2 queries? Also, you can remove the `ORDER BY` clause to improve performance, its not needed anyways if you are returning a single row.

Comment: Declan, I just updated my code example. The first query is selecting from the column "Count", while the second query is selecting from the column "Shipment".

Comment: Use one dataset with two fields `SELECT COUNT ,SHIPMENT FROM...`

Comment: If I use "SELECT TOP 1" and remove "ORDER BY" will I always get the latest record,even though there are multiple records in the column that I'm querying data from?

Comment: Apopreciate it. That works fine but what if I want to use a variable retrieve those values seperatly in my HTML For example if I use "SELECT top 1 Shipment, Count From..." and create one variable Shipment_D1 = rscount4 ("Shipment") I would only be able to retreive the whole query (which uses both columns "Shipment and Count") in my HTML using something like <%= Shipment_D1 %> I would like to use to variables

Comment: Nevermind I was over complicating it. I took a look at the comment below. I appreciate your help on this though